# Forced to use a sub-select, returning the latest

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is a newb question, but I have always had a block on sub queries.  I normally just use CTEs, but this question was on a test I took a few days ago, and I was required to use a sub-select.

Table is called CALL_DETAILS
Columns:

```
PHONE_NBR (Phone number)
CUSTOMER  (name)
CALL_TYPE (cell or land)
CALL_TIME (date and time of call)
DURATION  (number of minutes)
COST  (monetary)
```

Question on test:  "Now that you can find the records for each Customer and each CALL_TYPE that have the latest CALL_TIME How do you return all information from the CALL_DETAILS table for those rows?  Yes, we're looking for you to use a nested SELECT (sub-select) in this answer."

I wrote the following, but have been second-guessing myself ever since.

```
SELECT
PHONE_NBR
,CUSTOMER
,CALL_TYPE
,CALL_TIME
,DURATION
,COST
FROM CALL_DETAILS CD
WHERE CALL_TIME IN
   (SELECT MAX(CALL_TIME)
    FROM CALL_DETAILS CDS
    GROUP BY CUSTOMER, CALL_TIME)
    ;
```

Was this correct??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not correctly.  You can use a subquery, but here is a more accurate method:

```
WHERE CALL_TIME = (SELECT MAX(CD2.CALL_TIME)
                   FROM CALL_DETAILS CD2
                   WHERE CD2.CUSTOMER = CD.CUSTOMER
                  )
```

Your version has numerous problems.

- Presumably, `MAX_CALL_TIME` doesn't exist.  So you have a syntax error with the `MAX()` function.
- You are aggregating by `CALL_TIME`, so every call time will be in the set.
- You are using `IN`, so every record is going to match one of the call times -- well, at least every one that is not `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks!  MAX_CALL_TIME was a typo.  I was supposed to be MAX(CALL_TIME).

I definitely blew that sub query.